# Adding index/line number tooltip for lines in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I want to have a tooltip for my applicaiton using plotly.js where lines are dynamic. If I hover on 1st line it should show line1 and for 2nd line it should show line2 etc. By lines are dynamic I mean, user can draw lines on the image and hovering on the line should show corroponding line number. In the image for now I have 3 lines so hovering on them should show line1, line2 and line3.

[image]

Now user can draw more lines and tooltip also should also reflect the same number.

```
let plotCon = document.getElementById('plotlyContainer');
function loadImg(imgWidth, imgHeight, imgs) {  
  data = [
    {
      x: [],
      y: [],
      type: 'scatter',
      hovertemplate: ``,
    },
  ];
  layout = {
    autosize: false,
    width: imgWidth * scale,
    height: imgHeight * scale,
    hovermode: 'closest',
    showlegend: false,
    hoverlabel: {
      bgcolor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
      font: {
        size: 12
      }
    },
    colorway: ['#3f4ed4'],
    xaxis: {range: [0, slicedWidth], dtick: conversionFactor, ticks: 'outside', tickformat: '.2f', tickmode: 'linear', tickwidth: 2, showgrid: false, mirror: true, linecolor: 'black', linewidth: 1, fixedrange: true, gridcolor: 'black'},
    yaxis: {range: [slicedHeight, 0], dtick: conversionFactor, ticks: 'outside', tickformat: '.2f', tickmode: 'linear', tickwidth: 2, showgrid: false, mirror: true, linecolor: 'black', linewidth: 1, fixedrange: true, gridcolor: 'black'},
    margin: {
      l: 50,
      r: 20,
      b: 50,
      t: 30
    }
  };
  Plotly.newPlot('plotlyContainer', data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});  
}

plotCon.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var clickCor = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();      
    if(lineFlag && (spacebarFlag == false) && (navFlag == false)) {  
      data[cnt].hovertemplate = `Line: Line ${lineCount}`;
      data[cnt].x.push((plotCon._fullLayout.xaxis.p2d(e.clientX - clickCor.left)).toFixed(2));
      data[cnt].y.push((plotCon._fullLayout.yaxis.p2d(e.clientY - clickCor.top)).toFixed(2));      
      imageCorDisp.push("(" + (plotCon._fullLayout.xaxis.p2d(e.clientX - clickCor.left)).toFixed(2) + ", " + (plotCon._fullLayout.yaxis.p2d(e.clientY - clickCor.top)).toFixed(2) + ")");
      Plotly.update(plotCon, data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});
    }
    else{      
      var objClicked = {
        x: [],
        y: [],
        type: 'scatter'
      };
      objClicked.x.push((plotCon._fullLayout.xaxis.p2d(e.clientX - clickCor.left)).toFixed(2));
      objClicked.y.push((plotCon._fullLayout.yaxis.p2d(e.clientY - clickCor.top)).toFixed(2));
      objClicked.type = 'scatter';
      let tempdata = "(" + (plotCon._fullLayout.xaxis.p2d(e.clientX - clickCor.left)).toFixed(2) + ", " + (plotCon._fullLayout.yaxis.p2d(e.clientY - clickCor.top)).toFixed(2) + ")";
      imageCorDisp.push(tempdata);
      
      data.push(objClicked);      
      Plotly.update(plotCon, data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});
    }
  });
```

With the help of click listener I am able to draw lines and corrosponding points I am pushing to data variable so that data obect the points and plots accordingly. Any help would be appreciated.